# Why is my Update command updating all of the fields that have the same ID?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Using the update command, I want to change the `type_name` for a specific entry in the database, but it is changing the `type_name` for all the entries with the same `type_id`.

I need it to only change that individual entry's `type_name`, and not the `type_name` that is associated with all the entries with the same `type_id`.

I have an update query:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE photos
       LEFT JOIN types 
       ON photos.type_id = types.type_id
       SET photos.photo_title = $_POST['photo_title'], 
           types.type_name = $_POST['type_name']
       WHERE photos.photo_id = 3';
```

Here's the form I'm using:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input name="photo_title" type="text" value=""/>
    <textarea name="type_name"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update entry" />
</form>
```

Here's my database structure:

TABLE photos

- photo_id   PRIMARY KEY
- photo_title
- type_id   FOREIGN KEY

TABLE types

- type_id   PRIMARY KEY
- type_name

Comment: So how would you identify the "individual entry" of the types table? Your SQL says that all the rows in types with the given type_id need to be updated -- how do you identify the single one that needs to be updated, vs the ones that must not be?

Comment: Your code is awful in more ways than I can count. Use a primary key for updates. DO NOT INCLUDE POST VARIABLES IN YOUR SQL! EVER! Learn what SQL injection means and how to use parameters.

Comment: yeah I know spliff. I just did that here to make it easier to understand what i am trying to do. I am actually using a prepared statement and binding my variables, but i didn't want to make it more confusing for people who don't understand prepared statements.

Comment: Alex, i added my database structure. Does that help clarify things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that your join is producing the wrong set of data. You're joining the photos and types on type_id.

Now what you seem to be describing is that the types column may contain multiple rows with the same type___id. What does this mean? It means that your join will produce multiple pairs of `(photos,types)` for each photo (specifically, for each photo, the join will produce n rows, where n is the number of rows in types having the same type_id as the photo).

As for how to fix this, you should take a look at your database design. You seem to expect a unique row in types for each photo. How is this relationship expressed? That will enable you to get a proper `ON` clause for your join.

**UPDATE**

After looking at the table structure, it seems your database is expressing things slightly differently. As it stands you can have multiple photos with the same type (i.e. their typeid in the photos table is the same). Thus it is a bit meaningless to speak of changing the typename of just one such photo. You're merely updating the typename for a particular type, that happens to be the type of the photo whose name you were also updating.

Now what exactly are you trying to achieve, here?

- If you are trying to re categorize a particular photo, then you instead want to either create a new entry in the types table and point your photo to that new record, or find an existing photo with a matching name and point the photo at that record. (I presume you already have such code in your photo insertion logic. This should be similar)
- If you are trying to update the type description for a photo and all other photos with that type, then what you have will work just fine.

Comment: Yuliy, i added my database structure. Does that help clarify things?

Comment: Yes, it does. I added a little bit more to the answer based on that.

Comment: "you instead want to either create a new entry in the types table and point your photo to that new record" 

Can you give me some code examples of how I might achieve this? I want to make an if statement that will check if the type_name entered already exists in the type_name column and if it does, then change it to that specific type_id and if the type_name doesn't already exist, then insert a new record. 

Do you know how I might go about programming that out?

Comment: How are you handling assigning a type_id to a new photo? It should be something similar to that, I'd think. 

Here's the basic idea:
1. select type_id from types where type_name=NEWTYPENAME
2a. if that returns a row, update photos set type_id=RETURNED_TYPEID WHERE photo_id=PHOTOID
2b. if it did not return a row, insert a new row into types for the new type_name, then update photos set type_id=INSERTED_TYPEID where photo_id=PHOTOID

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that MySQL allows this, but it looks like you're updating the name in the type table.  You're probably looking to update the type_id of a single row in the photos table.

You could do that like this:

```
UPDATE photos
SET photos.photo_title = $_POST['photo_title'], 
    photos.type_id = (
        select type_id 
        from types 
        where type_name = $_POST['type_name']
    )
WHERE photos.photo_id = 3
```

Or alternatively:

```
UPDATE photos
LEFT JOIN types ON types.type_id = $_POST['type_name']
SET photos.photo_title = $_POST['photo_title'], 
    photos.type_id = types.type_id
WHERE photos.photo_id = 3
```

Before you run this query, you could make sure the type_name exists:

```
REPLACE INTO types (type_name) VALUES ($_POST['type_name'])
```

Comment: I think you're in the right direction, but when i implemented your code, it simply wiped out the id back to '0' so no type name showed up now. Any ideas?

Comment: If it sets the ID back to 0, the new name probably did not exist in the types table yet.  Did you try to run the REPLACE INTO query _before_ the UPDATE query?  The REPLACE INTO query would add the new type to the types table.

Answer (score 0):

> I need it to only change that
>   individual entry's type_name, and not
>   the type_name that is associated with
>   all the entries with the same type_id.

This is your fundamental problem. There's only ever going to be one record in the types database per `typeid`, so when you alter it, it effectively alters it for every photo that references that `typeid`.

If you need to store a different `type_name` for every photo, just create a column in the `photos` table and store it there.

The other way to do this is to create a new record in the `types` table each time a `type_name` is edited - possibly doing some checking to see whether any other photos are also using that `typeid` (if not you can safely update the existing record). But you have to implement code that does this for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If more than one row is being updated then you are not using a unique key to update the tables. It is difficult to understand the relationship of the tables but it seems to be a 1:M relationship one type can be appended to many photos?

If so then updating the photos table using the type_id in the WHERE clause will obviously update more than one table. Use only primary keys thats are unique to update if you want to update a specific row.

You must specify the relationships of the tables if you want a decent solution :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = 'UPDATE photos
       LEFT JOIN types 
       ON photos.type_id = types.type_id
       SET photos.photo_title = $_POST['photo_title'], types.type_name = $_POST['type_name']
       WHERE photos.photo_id = 3 LIMIT 1';
```

On a side note, you shoule be doing

```
$photo_title = escape_function( $_POST['photo_title'] )
$type_name = escape_function( $_POST['type_name'] )
```

and wrapping the varialble names in ' ' in your query string.

Comment: this will change just one row, but why would that row be the "right" one automagickally?!